# Manim:why is my graph plotted in half the animation time?

Tags: manim

I have this simple script, where I would like the ValueTracker (displayed as a number on the right) to evolve at the same speed with the graph. Instead the graph plotting finishes in 5 seconds. Do you know why and how to fix it?

```
from manim import *


class TrackerExample(Scene):

    def sin(self,x):
        f = 1 / 50
        return np.sin(x * 2 * math.pi * f) / 2 + 0.5

    def construct(self):

        axes= Axes(x_range=[0, 749, 100],
                            y_range=[0, 4, 2],
                            axis_config={"include_numbers": True, "font_size": 24},
                            x_axis_config={},
                            x_length=4,
                            y_length=3
                            ).move_to(LEFT * 2)



        self.play(Write(axes, lag_ratio=0.01, run_time=1))


        tracker = ValueTracker(0)


        sin_graph = axes.plot(lambda x: self.sin(x), color=BLUE)


        numbers = DecimalNumber(0).move_to(2*RIGHT)


        numbers.add_updater(lambda m: m.set_value(int(tracker.get_value())))


        self.add(numbers)


        self.play(tracker.animate.set_value(749), Write(sin_graph), run_time=10,
                  rate_func=linear)

example = TrackerExample()
example.construct()
```

I am using the community version of manim, 0.16.0.post0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to your choice of Animation: `Write` draws, in the first 50% of the animation run time, the stroke of the mobject and then fills it in the remaining 50% of the run time. Replace `Write` with `Create`, and it will look as expected.

And by the way, if you want to render your scene directly from the script, use the `render` method, not `construct`:

```py
example = TrackerExample()
example.render()
```